# Hardware Temperature report

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to find a way to report the hardware temperatures back to me without a program that I have to download, I know of plenty that do that show but don't report back to a remote location on the network.

I found an applescript that I might be able to modify to get it to work but I am currently stuck at step 1 right now, getting the script to run.

Below is the script that I found. I keep getting an error at the marked line, lucky line 13.
The error just says can't get item 17.

```
set the_result to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHWSensor | grep -vE '\\{|\\}|\\+\\-o'")'s paragraphs

set all_display to ""
repeat with i from 0 to 16

    set jump to 3
    set the_location to item (3 + (jump * i)) of the_result
    set the_location to characters 41 thru ((count of characters of the_location) - 1) of the_location as string
    set the_type to item (4 + (jump * i)) of the_result
    set the_text to item (2 + (jump * i)) of the_result as string
    **set the_text to characters 44 thru (count of characters of the_text) of the_text as string --(length of item 2 of the_result)**
    set the_type to characters 37 thru ((count of characters of the_type) - 1) of the_type as string
    if the_type = "temperature" then
        set all_display to all_display & "
" & the_location & ": " & ((the_text / 65536) * (9 / 5)) + 32 & " F" as string
    end if
end repeat

display dialog all_display
```

I was playing around with this again and finally able to get the complete error
Error: Can't make characters 44 thru 41 of "  | |  |   |  |    \"version\" = 2" into type string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this information is reported by the `IOHWSensor` via `ioreg`. This one-liner works for me:

```
echo $((`ioreg -c IOHWSensor | grep "current-value" | grep -oE [0-9]+` / 65536))
```

Division by `65536` may be hardware-dependent. Some macs store the value as a multiple of 10, other powers of 2, etc. After dividing by the correct number, I believe the result is always in ºC.

Further reading:
http://www.cminow.org/ioreg_perl.html

Answer (score 0):

Scrip searches for word "temperature" in the output of "ioreg -c IOHWSensor" command - but if you execute that from command line and grep for word "temperature" there will be none. At least I don't see it on my system.
Mine is OsX 10.7 what you have got there ?

Comment: 10.6.8
My understanding though is that all of the Intel Mac's will be largely similar.
Obviously though if they are not that would be one problem.
However, this script is erroring before Temperature.

Comment: My point was that it will never find temperature keyword. Anyway, you can simply remove  | grep -vE '\\{|\\}|\\+\\-o' from script and run it again. It is trying to get rid off +o\| symbols.